# How to check attribute value of current object in edit form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested model. How to check attribute value of object(hotel) of neted model in edit form? I can't figure out how to write if/else statement in _hotels_fields.html.erb

**edit.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit trip") %>
<h1>Edit trip</h1>

<%= form_for(@trip) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields_edit', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>
```

**_fields_edit.html.erb**

```
<p>
<%= f.label :image  %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
</p>

<p>Hotel</p>

<%= f.fields_for :hotels do |builder| %>
 <%= render 'hotels_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

**_hotels_fields.html.erb**

```
<% if  @trip.hotels.name == "hotel" %>

<p>Render any text</p>
<% end %>

<fieldset>

<p>
   <%= f.label :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.label :description %>
   <%= f.text_field :description %>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40309136/4111295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of `_hotels_fields.erb.html` one specific `hotels` (why plural here if you have only one?) is represented by `f.object`. Therefore this should work:

```
<% if f.object.name == 'hotel' %>
  ...
<% else %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I can't find out how to put if statement to this ":hotels" objects. I tried your suggestion but it dosn't work. Have you any ideas why? 

 <%= f.fields_for :hotels do |builder| %>

 <% if f.hotel.name == "name" %>
 <p> profit</p>
 <% end %>

  <%= builder.label :name %>
  <%= builder.text_field :name %>

   <%= builder.label :description %>
   <%= builder.text_field :description %>
 <% end %>

Comment: Now it seams like you mixed it up. If you have problems figuring out what object you have in your hands, try the following: Take the inner variable name from your form builder (was `f` in your first example, now `builder` in your comment) and call `<%= debug builder.object.inspect %>`.