# Get data attribute value from the Rails form builder without using input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what I hope to be a simple question.  I need to display the value for an attribute on the Edit page, while keeping the input field for the same attribute. How might this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well generally you can just use the original object, like you'll have an `@foo` that you'll have used in your `form_for` statement, so you can just use that directly: `= @foo.the_attribute`

If you're within a partial, or elsewhere where you have only the form builder instance, then you can refer to the underlying object with the `.object` method, eg.:

```
= form_for @foo do |f|
  # in here, f.object == @foo
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm working with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in two models. `Event` accept nested objects from `Speaker`. And `Speaker` has a `perfil_id` attribute which could be **['Maker', 'Developer', 'Entrepreneur', ...]**.

The `Speaker`'s form is a partial rendered from the principal form, `Event`'s form:

```
<%= form_for(event) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.label :title, 'Event name' %>

    <%= f.fields_for :speakers do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'events/partials/speaker_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

***Partial***

```
<%= builder.number_field :name %>
<%= builder.label :name %>

<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@profiles, 'id', 'name', f.object.member_profile_id ) %>
<%= select_tag "event[speakers_attributes][profile_id]", options, prompt: 'Select a Profile' %>
```

When ***editing*** Event's Speakers I wanted a `select_tag` to select the profile name for the actual Speaker.

I could not use an ***input field*** for this. So I need to get the correct values from the builder object and I get what I need by doing this:

`f.object.profile_id`

Passing it as a fourth param to the `select options` I get this working:

`<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@profiles, 'id', 'name', f.object.profile_id ) %>`

I hope it could be useful for you too!